# Windows 7 can't repair itself after motherboard replacement

Tags: windows-7, copy-protection

I know it is wrong place to ask but problem is really annoying. My laptop got broke, so laptop vendor replaced motherboard and now Windows 7 failed to start. I know that Microsoft finally over engineered copy protection, so some checksums of new BIOS didn't match with some registry setting. Unfortunately IT of my company is in other country, so I need to send my laptop overseas just to give IT person to insert original WIndows 7 disk and say this is your new laptop. Question is any simpler solution can be created by software engineers for protect software than spend hundred dollars for nothing?

Comment: Is it by any chance a HP notebook?

Comment: You are wrong about needing an original disk. The disk can be downloaded here: http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/ Then the key is, do you have a legitimate key?

Comment: Short answer, maybe, long answer, it is very complicated and takes way too much time, better to back up data and clean install W7.

Answer (score 1):

You never specified the exact error message you received, so I'll have to use my psychic skills. . .

If it really is an activation screen, sometimes you can just reactivate.  Sometimes you can't and for good reasons.

If you didn't run into an explicit activation screen, then there are couple of things you can do.  Try a system restore.  Then try the startup repair option.  Sometimes you'll need your install DVD, depending on how bad the damage is.

Or you could be running into a HAL problem, especially if your new laptop is significantly different from the older one.  HAL (hardware abstraction layer) is the low level part of Windows that is built during setup.  While Microsoft could of setup the HAL to support motherboard migration, it causes unnecessary performance issues and is a pain in the rear to test(bad testing = corrupt data = lawsuits).  Plus people already complain about the size of Windows as is.  Imagine if Microsoft also install each HAL available ( there are four different ones I believe).

In general, Most OSes were never design nor intended to be moved from motherboard to motherboard.  While it is possible, many IT folks including Microsoft, your IT department, and mine frown upon the practice.  It just brings up unknown consequences that may show up in the form of degraded performance or silent corruption of your data.

Most people recommend you reinstall your OS if you are moving to a new motherboard because the consequences are just too great and unknown.  I would suggest the advice to you.